# PnP PowerShell command "Add-PnPFieldToContentType" not working in any site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, content-type, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to use this PnP PowerShell command: `Add-PnPFieldToContentType` to assign some site columns to a specific content type. I've connected to the site collection using this command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $siteUrl –Credentials ($credential)
```

and other PnP commands are working just fine, but `Add-PnPFieldToContentType` throws me this error:

```
Add-PnPFieldToContentType : Field or property "ShowInDisplayForm" does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PnPFieldToContentType -Field "SPSNumber" -ContentType "East Asia  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFieldToContentType], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.ContentTypes.AddFieldToContentType
```

Where "SPSNumber" is the internal name of the column and "East Asia Contact" is the content type name. Here is the command I'm using:

```
Add-PnPFieldToContentType -Field "SPSWorkFlowName" -ContentType "example content type"
```

I think I have studied every article on the internet about `Add-PnPFieldToContentType` and none of them are doing any good.

I appreciate any idea.

Comment: Can you please add the command you are using in your question? where & how are you passing `ShowInDisplayForm`. which version of PnP PowerShell you are using?

Comment: I'm not using `ShowInDisplayForm` anywhere in the commands.
I'm using SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 3.29. I also added the command in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way around using Sharepoint Management Shell commands like this (I'm using Windows PowerShell ISE):

```
#Get Web Object
$web = Get-SPWeb "site url here"
 
#Get Content Type
$ContentType = $web.ContentTypes["content type name"]

#Get The Field
$FieldToAdd=$web.Fields["site column name"]
 
#Add Field to Content type
$FieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($FieldToAdd)
$ContentType.FieldLinks.Add($FieldLink)
$ContentType.Update()
```

Comment: this is the longest way to add field in content type. PnP is the shorter way. Unfortunately, the same happening to my script now. Unable to add field to content type. While, if I run the same line in command prompt. It works, but not working the same in function case

Answer (score 0):

I've tested below, and it worked for me. `Add-PnPFieldToContentType` uses **Internal** column/field name as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfieldtocontenttype?view=sharepoint-ps). You might try changing *SPSWorkFlowName* to internal name *SPSNumber* and try again.

```
Import-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Verbose

 
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/"
$ContentTypeName = "TestDocCT"
$SiteColumnName = "WorkflowName" #Internal Name
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred
     
    #Add Field to Content type
    Add-PnPFieldToContentType -Field $SiteColumnName -ContentType $ContentTypeName
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Comment: I'm using internal names for columns and still get the same error, which is:
`Add-PnPFieldToContentType : Field or property "ShowInDisplayForm" does not exist.`